# Bash-script: How to combine a command with a variable name?

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script.
I want to be able to change the numbers assigned to -tot_src, etc, in the below line
that is included in the bash script.
How do I do this?

```
./eperftool -tot_src=250 -tot_rep=200 -loss=3:200
```

First step would be to declare e.g. the following:

```
TOT_SRC = 273
```

I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
 ./eperftool -tot_src=$TOT_SRC -tot_rep=200 -loss=3:200
```

Comment: `TOT_SRC = 273` should be `TOT_SRC=273` without white space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to most programming languages, bash is sensitive to blanks in assignments.

right:

```
TOT_SRC=273
```

wrong:

```
TOT_SRC = 273
```